# Square root function in VBA, Excel

Tags: vba, excel

What is the square root function in VBA excel? I tried SQRT() and Root() but none of them are working, my Excel version in 2013.

Comment: =SQRT() should do what you want. If you explain why is it not working it could help.

Comment: For VBA there is no `WorksheetFunction.SQRT` but you can use `WorksheetFunction.Power(64, 1/2)` if you need to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the oddly named

`VBA.Sqr(n)`

where `n` is your number for which you want the square root computed. The `VBA.` prefix is optional, but it helps descriminate between `VBA` and any other library you might have referenced.

Comment: Even though it's called "Sqr", it is, in fact, the VBA Square Root function. To Square a number, simply use the "^" operator. (It's not XOR, it's "to the power of")

Answer (score 1):

[Nth root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) can be obtained with VBA with:

```
Option Explicit

Function NthRoot(dblNumber As Double, lngRoot As Long) As Double
    NthRoot = dblNumber ^ (1 / lngRoot)
End Function
```

So for square root:

```
? NthRoot(64, 2)
 8 
? NthRoot(64.33333, 2)
 8.02080606921773
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [^ operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264365.aspx) to obtain square roots. Just raise the number you started with to the power of 0.5:

`81^0.5` will give you 9 and `256^0.5` will give you 16

Answer (score 0):

Sqr : is the function used to calcualte the sqare root, or you can use ^0.5

```
Function getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2)

getDistance = Sqr((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)


End Function
```